# Cascade update on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a class `Yojana` and another class `Kabuliyat`, where Kabuliyat belongs to Yojana, and a Yojana has one kabuliyat.

```
class Yojana < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :kabuliyat, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Kabuliyat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :yojana
end
```

Some of the fields/attributes of a **kabuliat instance** are dependent on the attributes of the **yojana instance**.

For example in partial form for a **new kabuliyat**.

```
- @yojana = Yojana.find_by_id(params[:yojana_id])

= form_for kabuliyat do |f|
tr
    td = f.label :yojana_name
    td = f.text_field :yojana_name, {value: @yojana.yojana_name,class: "hide-input",:readonly => true}

tr
    td = f.label :mukhya_samiti
    td = f.text_field :mukhya_samiti, {value: @yojana.mukhya_samiti,class: "hide-input",:readonly => true}
```

As you can see, the attributes such as **:yojana_name** and **:mukhya_samitit** for a kabuliyat instance are extracted from it's parent yojana instances attribute.

**Problem:**

I wanted to know, if I had an instance of kabuliyat saved, and then I edited the Yojana's instance on whom the Kabuliyat's attributes are dependent on, how would I be able to also reflect the changes on the kabuliyat's instance.

*For example*: If I change the name of a Yojana instance from "A" to "B", can this change be automatically reflected on the child instance kabuliyat's attribute(for example: yojana_name) automatically.

**What I have tried:**

I used the `before_update` callback in the **Yojana.rb** model class, and manually made changed to all the other depended classes on Yojana. I wanted to know if there was any other efficient method.

Comment: I have found that ActiveRecord callbacks, like `before_update` become painfully complicated in large systems. I like the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). In your case, I might have a `UpdateYojana` class that updates the `Yojana`, then updates the `Kabuliyat`. It's easier to test than a callback, I think.

Comment: Can you give me more insight on the UpdateYojana class.

Answer (score 2):

Create a service, `UpdateYojana`, you can do something like this,

```
class UpdateYojana
  attr_reader :yojana, :kabuliyat

  def initialize(yojana)
    @yojana = yojana
    @kabuliyat = yojana.kabuliyat
  end

  def self.update(yojana_id, params)
    yojana = Yojana.find(yojana_id)
    new(yojana).update(params)
  end

  def update(params)
    return false unless valid?

    ApplicationRecord.transaction do
      if yojana.yojana_name_changed? or yojana.mukhya_samiti_changed?
        kabuliyat.update!(yojana_name: yojana.yojana_name, mukhya_samiti: yojana.mukhya_samiti)  
      end
      yojana.save!
    end
  end

  private

  def valid?(params)
    params.each do |attr, value|
      yojana.public_send("#{attr}=", value)
    end
    yojana.valid?
  end
end
```

Ofcourse, you can make a lot of improvement to the code, but this is just to give an idea about how you can approach to this problem.

Comment: Nice example Rajdeep. This is exactly what I was [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292591/cascade-update-on-association?noredirect=1#comment106651084_60292591). I like this better than callbacks because the model is simpler, and `UpdateYojana` can be tested easily.